# Why does prototype's Ajax request take so long to process?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I'm using prototype.js and its Ajax object to implement an interactve graph widget.  I generate an XML query for the data the user wants, POST it to the server with an Ajax.request, and it seems to take forever with Firefox.  The Firebug console seems to show the POST finishes with 200 OK in about 700 ms, but the onInteractive() handler I installed (which prototype triggers when readyState == 3) fires multiple times over the next TWELVE SECONDS, and then my onSuccess handler processes the data.

Anyone know what's going on here before I dig into the code?

Comment: How much are you returning in your response?

Comment: About a megabyte of XML text, depending on the query range.

Comment: A quick awk script later shows that a more-or-less compact JSON representation will be about a factor of 20 smaller, so server-side script here I come.  I'd hoped to avoid it -- better to have one thing to maintain than two -- but the performace gain will be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what was happening was that Firebug was showing the POST finishing when readystate was 4, but not reporting the whole transaction finished until my onSuccess handler had finished, and the with the megabyte of XML that was taking quite a while.  Switching to the more compact JSON representation instead of XML reduced the tedious XML parsing to, more or less:

```
eval(responseText); doGraph();
```

Thanks for the comments, guys, they weren't exactly what I needed but they pointed me in the right direction, and the feature is now working very slickly.

Answer (score 1):

With readyState 3, the XHR-request is still in process, so that may trigger your `onInteractive` handler multiple times. What does it do? Why can't you use one callback and have it fired on `readyState === 4`? Furthermore you could try using the net panel of Firebug ('Net' tab on top) to see what takes all that time.

Comment: All the "onInteractive" handler does is log that it fired; it's strictly for debugging.  I was trying to figure out why it was taking so long after Firebug claimed the XHR was finished.

The Net tab is a good idea, thanks.